# using arrow functions inside class and using it in the constructor - nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint, arrow-functions

I have a class called the user, where I have a method called getDetails. I am using the arrow function for the method.

the problem is when i use arrow function eslint shows error, for the = (equal) so I have added the babel-eslint. Now the eslint error is not showing but when I run the code it is showing

**SyntaxError: Unexpected token =**

// index.js

```
class User{
  constructor(){
    this.users = this.getUsers()
  }

  getUsers = () => {
    return ["test1", "test2"]
  }
}
```

// eslintrc

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb-base",
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "jest": true
  },
 .........
..........
}
```

I am using node version of 8.11.1. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

`getUsers()` is a class method, so you should use the following syntax below.

```js
class User {
    constructor() {
        this.users = this.getUsers()
    }

    getUsers() {
        return ["test1", "test2"]
    }
}

console.log(new User().users);
```

Comment: thanks for the response ,so this is a normal function method , if i use arrow function i am getting error in nodejs . Please check the question

Comment: if you try to run the snippet in console of chrome also you will get the same error. any idea on this

Comment: I don't know if I understood your comments. Are you having an error in the chrome console with the solution I posted now or with your initial one? Because I tested the solution I posted, in the browser console, and it's ok.

Comment: In a Class you are creating a method and not a normal function. You could, for example, use an arrow function in the constructor properties but not as a method. This doc helps https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

Comment: with the initial one that i have asked in the question. If i use a normal function method it will, but why when i use arrow functions it is not  working. Is it because we need a babel to transpile it ?

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using two ways.

1) Creating the arrow function inside the constructor like this,

```
    class User {
    constructor() {
        this.users = () => {
            return ["test1", "test2"]
        }
    }
}
```

2) use `node --harmony` to execute it with arrow function. Harmony flag enables the ES6 features.